# List child pages only if specific custom field is not empty in those pages

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I have this function to list all child pages and I want it to don't list those elements which does not have custom field "role" or if this custom field is empty. I've tried different things but even if I type value or meta value "test" all pages are listed. There's something wrong with this query meta_key is working perfectly but meta_value doesn't work.

My function code is this:

```
function list_child_pages() {
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'meta_key'      => 'role',
        'meta_value' => 'test',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        return list_childs();
    } else
        $string="team members were not found";
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: how about in your loop, you can if(get_field('role')){ //echo your stuff here }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'AND',
    [
        'key'     => 'role',
        'value'   => 'test',
        'compare' => '='
    ]
],
```

I prefer to use `[]` instead of `array()`

But you can also have

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'role',
        'value'   => 'test',
        'compare' => '='
    )
),
```

**Integration with your example:**

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'role',
            'value'   => 'test',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
);
```

Try to read the documentation of the `Class WP_Meta_Query` at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query